# Why are my hover effects in CSS not being applied to my top nav but are working on my footer nav?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been created hover effects to my top nav and footer nav in CSS. However for some reason the CSS applied to the bottom nav are showing but not the ones applied to the top nav. This is my HTML & CSS code. The links in the footer are changing to color grey on hover but the links in the header are not. Is there something I'm doing wrong in structuring the way CSS applies for the nav links in the header?

````css
```
   @font-face {
  font-family: 'HelveticaPro';
  src: url(/public/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn.ttf) format('truetype');
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

body {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* NAV CSS */
.header{
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

nav{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* nav ul li a {
  color: white;
} */
.logo{
  width: 80px;
}
.left a{
  margin-left: 20px; 
  color: white; 
}
.right a{
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white; 
}
 .back-video{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
  .back-video{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
  }
 }
 @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
  .back-video{
width: auto;
height: 100%;
  }
 }
.content{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.content h1{
  font-size: 10vw;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.content a{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 50;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}


/* Footer CSS */
footer{
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /* background-color: black; */
}
.footer-content {
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
}
.nav-footer{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1vw;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav-footer-item a{
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 1.875vw;
  list-style: none;
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.newsletter{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.newsletter img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

/* Main Section CSS */
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
}

/* Hover Effects CSS */

.right a:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
}
.left a:hover{
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-footer-item a:hover{
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```
````

```html
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <div class="header">

    <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
      <source src="videos/Screen Print Halftones Portraits _ a look into Unfinished Legacy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="left"><a href="#">Mens</a></li>
          <li class="left"><a href="#">Womens</a></li>
          <li class="left"><a href="#">Accesories</a></li>
        </ul>
            
        <a href="#"> 
          <img src="images/dist.png" alt="Garment Dist." class="logo">
        </a> 
        
        <ul>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li class="right"><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Garment Dist.</h1>
      <a href="#">Discover</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   

  <!-- Footer  -->

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <div class="newsletter">
        <img src="images/dist.png">
      </div>
        <ul class="nav-footer">
          <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
          <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

I applied the following CSS to the bottom nav using its class selector for the  elements and it worked just fine. So I did it the same way to create this effect to the top nav with the .right class links and no dice.

Comment: The links inside "right" are changing color to grey in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your html and saw that your div of class header that you have 2 sets of lists, one with list items of a class of left and another with right.
I'm assuming that you also want the class of left to change when hovered above so i suggest adding a class with left hover to your css to change the color like what ive added:

```css
.left a:hover{
  color: grey;
}
```

Let me know if this was helpful or if I interpreted what you need to fix incorrectly

Also I suggest that as you have a footer element you can use a header element with a class of navbar or sorts so your code will be more easily readable

**Updated Answer**
Seeing as my first solution didn't work you can also try setting an initial color and a hover color for both right and left items in your css file

```css
.right a{
  color: black;

.right a:hover{
  color: grey;

.left a{
  color: black;

.left a:hover{
  color: grey;
}
```

Comment: No I have tried adding both none of it actually shows the hover effect. I just tried to apply the effect to the right class of list items first to check if it work or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would you like. me to send my full css code, that way you can perhaps see if any other code is interfering with this.

Comment: CSS Code updated

Comment: Saw your updated code and that you put your solution below. Great that you were able to solve it. Have fun creating your website!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I just had to give the `nav` element a `z-index:1` to make the effects show. Because I believe the background-video in the header was in front of the nav and was causing the effects to be hidden.